# Refactoring Document Writer headings

Tags: c#

I am working on a Document Writer that writes documentation for software deliveries. It all works in its current state but I am needing to refactor a C# method. The app reaches to TFS and pulls down a work item and writes it in Word.

This method deals with writing the headings for sections and subsections of the document. You can see lambda usage at the beginning that gathers the info to be written and at the end the original setup before refactoring to its current state is commented out in the end. The method reads an AreaPath listed as `root\space1\space2\...` and splits at the `\` to get the length. Then on the document it is written as "3.0 Root...3.1 Space 1...3.2 Space 2...".

```
private void InsertReqSection()
    {
        //connectToServerManual();
        System.Data.DataTable AreaPathsList = GetAllAreaPaths(project.ProjectName);

        InsertText("Functional Requirements", WdBuiltinStyle.wdStyleHeading1);

        if (project.AllLinksRequirements.Count > 0)
        {
            List<Requirement> sortedList = project.AllLinksRequirements.OrderBy(o => o.Category).ThenBy(o => o.CharId).ToList();
            List<Requirement> areaPathOrderedList = new List<Requirement>();
            List<string> sectionHeadingList = new List<string>();
            string currentArea = string.Empty;
            string nextArea = string.Empty;
            Table table = null;

            for (int i = 0; i < AreaPathsList.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                foreach (Requirement req in sortedList)
                {
                    if (req.AreaPath == AreaPathsList.Rows[i]["Path"].ToString())
                    {
                        areaPathOrderedList.Add(req);
                    }
                }
            }

            foreach(Requirement req in areaPathOrderedList)
            {
                nextArea = req.AreaPath;
                string[] areaNames = nextArea.Split('\\');

                if (nextArea != currentArea)
                {
                    int areaPathLength = areaNames.Length;

                    if (!sectionHeadingList.Contains(areaNames[1]))
                    {
                        sectionHeadingList.Clear();
                        sectionHeadingList.Add(areaNames[1]);
                        WriteUsingHeadingStyle2(areaNames[1]);
                    }
                   
                    if (areaPathLength >= 3 && !sectionHeadingList.Contains(areaNames[2]))
                    {
                        sectionHeadingList.Add(areaNames[2]);
                        WriteUsingHeadingStyle3(areaNames[2]);
                    }

                    switch (areaPathLength)
                    {
                        case 4:
                            sectionHeadingList.Add(areaNames[3]);
                            WriteUsingHeadingStyle4(areaNames[areaNames.Length - 1]);
                            break;
                        case 5:
                            sectionHeadingList.Add(areaNames[4]);
                            WriteUsingHeadingStyle5(areaNames[areaNames.Length - 1]);
                            break;
                        case 6:
                            if (!sectionHeadingList.Contains(areaNames[5]))
                                WriteUsingHeadingStyle5(areaNames[areaNames.Length - 2]);
                            WriteUsingHeadingStyle6(areaNames[areaNames.Length - 1]);
                            break;
                        default:
                            break;
                    }


                    //  if (areaNames.Length > 4)
                    //  {
                    //      if (areaNames.Length == 6)
                    //      {
                    //          WriteUsingHeadingStyle5(areaNames[areaNames.Length - 2]);
                    //          WriteUsingHeadingStyle6(areaNames[areaNames.Length - 1]);
                    //      }
                    //      else if (areaNames.Length == 5)
                    //          WriteUsingHeadingStyle5(areaNames[areaNames.Length - 1]);
                    //  }  
                    //  else if (areaNames.Length == 4)
                    //      WriteUsingHeadingStyle4(areaNames[areaNames.Length - 1]);


                    currentArea = nextArea;
                    table = InsertAndFormatReqTable();
                }

                AddReqRow(table, req);
                
            }
        }
        else
        {
            InsertText("There are no requirements listed in the Project.", WdBuiltinStyle.wdStyleNormal);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

### `var` when appropriate

These lines:

```
            List<Requirement> areaPathOrderedList = new List<Requirement>();
            List<string> sectionHeadingList = new List<string>();
```

have an obvious type, so you can replace them with `var`. For your other variables, keep them as-is since their type is not obvious on inspection.

### C-style loops

```
        for (int i = 0; i < AreaPathsList.Rows.Count; i++)
```

should be replaced with a `foreach`, since you do not use the index.

### Parsing

Looking at how you use fixed indices into the `areaNames` array, it's likely that `req.AreaPath` is a string that needs to be parsed out into its own class with meaningful field names rather than numerical indices into a split string. Given your current code I have no idea what those fields would be, but this is what traditional OOP would push you toward. It would be more legible and maintainable.

### Early-return

This is a matter of style, but I find this:

```
        if (project.AllLinksRequirements.Count > 0)
        {
             // most of the method
        }
        else
        {
            InsertText("There are no requirements listed in the Project.", WdBuiltinStyle.wdStyleNormal);
        }
```

to be more legible as

```
if (project.AllLinksRequirements.Count < 1)
{
    InsertText("There are no requirements listed in the Project.", WdBuiltinStyle.wdStyleNormal);
    return;
}

// The rest of the method
```

It allows you a good deal of de-indentation, as well as dealing with the simpler case first.

Comment: Thank you. These are all great suggestions. My question is for your suggestion of C-style loops, is my index of `[i]` not being used within `AreaPathsList.Rows[i]["Path"].ToString()`? When I change to a `foreach` it becomes an undefined variable and I lose the ability to keep track of where in the original sorted list I am at.

Comment: When you replace `AreaPathsList.Rows[i]` with your loop variable, all of your references to `i` will go away.

Answer (score 2):

Quick remarks:

- Do not call things "xxxxList". The type might change and thus the name might become invalid, but more importantly we don't call a collection of items an "xxxxList" in real life, we simply use the plural: `areas`, `requirements`, etc.
- Use descriptive names: `sortedList` tells me next to nothing about the contents of that collection.
- Be consistent: you use both "sorted" and "ordered", which suggests these are different concepts to you. Which means the next developer needs to figure out what distinction you make and why. (Then again, such terms really shouldn't be part of a name anyway.)
- Why does `GetAllAreaPaths` return a `DataTable`? Why not return a collection of a custom class?
- Things like `areaNames[1]` are non-descriptive. Store these values in a properly named variable.
- I see methods like `WriteUsingHeadingStyle2`, `WriteUsingHeadingStyle3`, etc. Why not have a `Write` method that has the `HeadingStyle` as the second parameter?
- Do not pointlessly abbreviate, e.g. `AddReqRow`. Your code will not execute faster because you abbreviated `Requested` to `Req`. Or is it `Required`?